# Error when Batch writing to dynamo (AttributeValue has more than one datatypes set) sdk v3

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to write to dynamo in batch and am currently getting this error in Cloudwatch logs

```
Supplied AttributeValue has more than one datatypes set, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes
```

My logic to write to dynamo in batch is as follows

```
const writeThingsInBatch = async (things: Things[], accountId: string, key: string): Promise<void> => {
    if (!tableName) {
        throw new Error(DynamoError.InvalidTableName);
    }

    const putRequests: PutRequest[] = things.map((thing) => ({ Item: enhancedSearchFilterToItem(key, accountId, thing) }));
    const putRequestChunks: PutRequest[][] = chunk(putRequests, 25); //lodash

    for (const putRequestChunk of putRequestChunks) {
        try {
            console.log("Request chunk", JSON.stringify(putRequestChunk))
            const data = await dynamoClient.send(new BatchWriteCommand({ RequestItems: { tableName: putRequestChunk } }));
            console.log("data from batch", { data })
            if (data.UnprocessedItems) {
                console.warn("Some items have not been processed in BatchWriteCommand", { UnprocessedItems: data.UnprocessedItems });
                return;
            }
            return;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error when Batch writing to dynamo", { error });
        }
    }
};
```

Just after the `try` I have a log to check on what the chunk that I'm adding to the `Request.tableName` looks like and from what I can see there the data looks correct

```
[
    {
        "Item": {
            "key": "d43ecafc-233e-35e2-a7c0-124e833123b3",
            "reference": "61498eeaa995ad0073bb8444#0010250",
            "code": "numberOfComments = 2",
            "allowed": true,
            "isSyncable": true,
            "syncIt": "1676972136978"
        }
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "key": "d43ecafc-233e-35e2-a7c0-124e833123b3",
            "reference": "61498eeaa995ad0073bb8444#0010251",
            "code": "numberOfComments = 2",
            "allowed": true,
            "isSyncable": true,
            "syncIt": "1676972136978"
        }
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "key": "d43ecafc-233e-35e2-a7c0-124e833123b3",
            "reference": "61498eeaa995ad0073bb8444#0010252",
            "code": "numberOfComments = 2",
            "allowed": true,
            "isSyncable": true,
            "syncIt": "1676972136978"
        }
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "key": "d43ecafc-233e-35e2-a7c0-124e833123b3",
            "reference": "61498eeaa995ad0073bb8444#0010253",
            "code": "numberOfComments = 2",
            "allowed": true,
            "isSyncable": true,
            "syncIt": "1676972136978"
        }
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "key": "d43ecafc-233e-35e2-a7c0-124e833123b3",
            "reference": "61498eeaa995ad0073bb8444#0010254",
            "code": "numberOfComments = 2",
            "allowed": true,
            "isSyncable": true,
            "syncIt": "1676972136978"
        }
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "key": "d43ecafc-233e-35e2-a7c0-124e833123b3",
            "reference": "61498eeaa995ad0073bb8444#0010255",
            "code": "numberOfComments = 2",
            "allowed": true,
            "isSyncable": true,
            "syncIt": "1676972136978"
        }
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "key": "d43ecafc-233e-35e2-a7c0-124e833123b3",
            "reference": "61498eeaa995ad0073bb8444#0010256",
            "code": "numberOfComments = 2",
            "allowed": true,
            "isSyncable": true,
            "syncIt": "1676972136978"
        }
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "key": "d43ecafc-233e-35e2-a7c0-124e833123b3",
            "reference": "61498eeaa995ad0073bb8444#0010257",
            "code": "numberOfComments = 2",
            "allowed": true,
            "isSyncable": true,
            "syncIt": "1676972136978"
        }
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "key": "d43ecafc-233e-35e2-a7c0-124e833123b3",
            "reference": "61498eeaa995ad0073bb8444#0010258",
            "code": "numberOfComments = 2",
            "allowed": true,
            "isSyncable": true,
            "syncIt": "1676972136978"
        }
    },
]
```

I have been reading a few posts and so far the errors people have don't seem to be what I do unless I'm missing something really easy. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, in case someone falls into this, the solution was to actually include the request type we make to dynamo `PutRequest` in each of the items included in the array for `RequestItems.tableName`.

Updated code below

```
type BatchPutRequest = {
    PutRequest: PutRequest
}

const writeFiltersInBatch = async (filters: EnhancedSearchFilter[], accountId: string, clientKey: string): Promise<void> => {
    if (!esFilterTableName) {
        throw new Error(DynamoError.InvalidTableName);
    }

    const putRequests: BatchPutRequest[] = filters.map((filter) => ({ PutRequest: { Item: enhancedSearchFilterToItem(clientKey, accountId, filter) } }));
    const putRequestChunks: BatchPutRequest[][] = chunk(putRequests, 25);

    for (const putRequestChunk of putRequestChunks) {
        try {
            console.log("Request chunk", JSON.stringify(putRequestChunk))
            const data = await dynamoClient.send(new BatchWriteCommand({ RequestItems: { esFilterTableName: putRequestChunk } }));
            console.log("data from batch", { data })
            if (data.UnprocessedItems) {
                console.warn("Some items have not been processed in BatchWriteCommand", { UnprocessedItems: data.UnprocessedItems });
                return;
            }
            return;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error when Batch writing to dynamo", { error });
        }
    }
};
```